# Should I use separate tables for this data?

Tags: mysql, database

This is a backend for a project I've been working on for fun that stores user's scorecards of boxing matches. Should I have a separate table for every boxing match (about 25 columns), or should I store every boxing match in the same table and add a column denoting which boxing match the row is for?

What are good standards to practice when making this decision? I will be accessing the table by averaging all rounds of a given match and returning the average score for all users for any given round. This type of access makes me think a separate table for each match would be desirable because that way I wouldn't be searching through any unwanted matches when trying to average the scores of a certain match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put each match in its own table. That would mean you would need an unknown number of tables, which is an indication that you have not modeled the problem correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. So generally it is more important to keep your number of tables at a conservative number as opposed to the number of rows in a given table?

Comment: Right. Rows are "free", the SQL engine's job is to deal with them for you. But tables are your "job" and you want to use the fewest number you can and still solve the problem.

Comment: @Adam Johns: It's not really about a "conservative number" of tables. It's about each table representing one type of thing, table named "vehicle" would contain rows that represent specific instances of vehicles... the attributes might be make, model, year, doors, owner, and VIN (VIN would be a candidate for a unique identifier, no two vehicles will have the same VIN.)

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to identify each "entity" within the model.

An entity is a person, place, thing, concept or event that

1. can be uniquely identified
2. we can store information about and
3. is important to the business or enterprise

An entity is implemented as a table, with each row in the table representing a single instance of the entity.

In the example, it sounds like a "boxing match" is an entity. The next step is figure out what the unique identifier is, whether it's a single column, or a combination of columns, and plan on having a UNIQUE INDEX defined on that.

In addition to the natural key(s), we typically introduce a surrogate `id` column which serves as the primary key of each entity table. (I will note that there are two schools of thought on whether a surrogate key is desirable: there are those who have elected to use a natural key as the primary key and have been later burned by that decision, and then there are those that haven't yet been burned by their decision to use a natural key as the primary key.)

The ideal primary key has these characteristics:

1. simple (a single attribute which is simple native datatype, e.g. int)
2. unique (a value identifies only a single row, no two rows have the same value)
3. anonymous (carries no visible or hidden information)
4. immutable (once value assigned, it is not changed)

Comment: So it sounds like your answer suggests I should make a separate table for each match. Do Dwayne's concerns worry you at all?

Comment: @AdamJohns: I concur with Dwayne. My answer suggests that you create  a single table named "boxing_match", and that you insert a row for each instance of a boxing match. The table will contain columns, which will store the attributes (i.e. the information about each boxing match.) One of those attributes (or a combination of those attributes) needs to uniquely identify the row.

Comment: @AdamJohns: to store information about vehicles, we'd create a table named "vehicle", with columns for make, model, year, list price, color, VIN, and so on. The Vehicle Identification Number (VIN) is a candidate for a unique identifier. There will likely be several rows that have the same value for make (e.g. Ford, Honda), but no two vehicles will have the same VIN.

Comment: Ok, thanks Spencer I see what you are saying now. I misread your answer the first time, and I thought you meant that each boxing match was an entity and every entity should have its own table. Thanks for the help.